# MYSQL SELECT SUM() BY DATE IF NO MATCH RETURN 0

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum, where-clause

I have connected three tables to each other.
I'm querying keywords + statistics.

I need to get data out by date range, and
if there is no data for that specific date range
i would like it to return 0 statistics

Lets say my query is:
SELECT keyword,SUM(stat) FROM keywords WHERE date >='2012-07-10' GROUP BY keyword;
It would return
|my keyword 1|3|
|my keyword 2|6|

Example table content:
| id | keyword          | stat | date            | keywordGroup |
| 1  | my keyword 1 | 2     | 2012-07-11 | 1 |
| 2  | my keyword 1 | 1     | 2012-07-12 | 1 |
| 3  | my keyword 2 | 6     | 2012-07-11 | 1 |
| 4  | my keyword 3 | 10   | 2012-07-09 | 1 |

But there are some keywords which have no stats for that date range
but I would still like to get those keywords showing 0 as stats. 
Like this:

|my keyword 1|3|
|my keyword 2|6|
|my keyword 3|0|
The problem is that the where clause blocks values that are not found, is there a workaround.
As I said I have three tables with relations, I use LEFT JOIN to
query data, for simplification I left that part out of my example query.

Table: Campaigns
id
name

Table: KeywordGroup
id
name
campaign

Table: KeywordData
id
keyword
stat
date
keywordGroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are joing tables with left joins correctly, use:

```
select keyword, ifnull(sum(stat),0) ... group by keyword
```

If it is WHERE clause that filters out some stats before even grouping is applied, then you need to move the date condition into LEFT JOIN condition, ie.

```
from KeywordGroup left join KeywordData on ... and date > '2012-07-10'
```

But I cannot help further without seeing actual queries. :-)

Comment: SELECT keyword,SUM(stat) FROM campaigns LEFT JOIN keywordGroup ON campaigns.id=keywordGroup.campaign LEFT JOIN keywordData ON keywordGroup.id=keywordData.keywordGroup WHERE keywordData.date>='2012-07-10' GROUP BY keyword

Comment: Data is being inserted to the keywordData table daily, lets say I keep records of google keyword visits daily, and if there are no visits for that day for that keyword, no data is inserted. I still need to get those keywords that has had 0 visits within my date range. Hmm well maybe I could query those separately like WHERE MAX(date)<='2012-07-09'

Comment: OK, I see a different problem here. The only place, where the actual keyword text is kept is "keyword" column in "keywordData" table right?

Comment: Right, would you suggest storing keyword separately? There will be same keyword multiple times only date is gonna change. And sure there will be multiple keywords

Comment: Yes, because you need some source that your "my keyword 3" comes from... Alternatively you can try Madhivanan solution but this can go really slow in some scenarios. Actually you only need these "distinct keyword" in separate table.

Comment: There will be from 1 to 20 million rows per year, and increasing each year, I thought I sorted out the problem of doing one more separate table using group by, but I see what went wrong. Madhivanan solution sure would work, but I think you are right here about doing separate table for keywords. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select 
    t1.keyword,
    sum(t2.stat) as stat
from
(   
    select distinct keyword from keywords   
) as t1 left join
(
    SELECT keyword,SUM(stat) FROM keywords WHERE date >='2012-07-10' GROUP BY keyword
) as t2
on t1.keyword=t2.keyword;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at a left outer join? Here's a good reference for the join types:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

```
"To produce the set of records only in Table A, but not in Table B, 
we perform a left outer join, then exclude the records we don't want 
from the right side via a where clause."
```

**ns**

Comment: The data is inside the same table so I think no use of outer join